# socket bind exception when tomcat is started

Tags: tomcat

I use `Tomcat 6`
I want to configure `ssl`. I've generated `.keystore` file and uncommented

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
           keystore="C:/Users/Admin/.keystore" keypass="changeit"/>
```

`Log` looks like this

```
сен 20, 2014 4:53:32 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
сен 20, 2014 4:53:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1660 ms
сен 20, 2014 4:53:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
сен 20, 2014 4:53:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37
сен 20, 2014 4:53:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor miniq.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor miniq.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive reservation.war
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] ?????? ??????????? ?????? ???? ????????????? ?????? ?????? (????????/??????? ?????/????).  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.start(AprEndpoint.java:851)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.start(Http11AprProtocol.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] ?????? ??????????? ?????? ???? ????????????? ?????? ?????? (????????/??????? ?????/????).  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] ?????? ??????????? ?????? ???? ????????????? ?????? ?????? (????????/??????? ?????/????).  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.init(AprEndpoint.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.start(AprEndpoint.java:851)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol.start(Http11AprProtocol.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1196)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
SEVERE: Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] ?????? ??????????? ?????? ???? ????????????? ?????? ?????? (????????/??????? ?????/????).  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1203)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
сен 20, 2014 4:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1162 ms
сен 20, 2014 4:53:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor miniq.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor miniq.xml
сен 20, 2014 4:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
сен 20, 2014 4:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
сен 20, 2014 4:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
```

And here my `server.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">

  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <!-- JMX Support for the Tomcat server. Documentation at /docs/non-existent.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container", 
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" 
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF8"/>
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->           
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the 
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystore="C:/Users/Admin/.keystore" keypass="changeit"/>


    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">         
    --> 
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->        

      <!-- The request dumper valve dumps useful debugging information about
           the request and response data received and sent by Tomcat.
           Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
      <!--
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/>
      -->

      <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
        -->

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

(Preliminarily, congratulations on asking with the good information.)

You have APR available in your Tomcat install and as a result  uses the APR (native) connector. APR uses OpenSSL to implement SSL instead of JSSE (the Java implementation) and OpenSSL configuration is different from Java/JSSE; in particular your key&cert need to be in OpenSSL files instead of a Java keystore, see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html .

I'm a bit alarmed the exception text is nearly all question marks; there should be something more useful there. But I see the month in your dates are non-English, so the question marks might just be some l10n (locale) problem. The log does show two APR connectors failing to bind, and you have two connectors configured that default to APR, one SSL and one not, which suggests some error other than (before?) the OpenSSL part.

If you can't get APR to work, you could select the Java connector by commenting out AprLifeCycleListener and/or specifying protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" (and use JSSE style SSL) to see if you get better results or at least a more helpful error message. This might not provide the same peak performance as native, but walk before you run.